Access amazon Secret Manager from .NET 8.0 web app outside of aws environment
I am trying to access the AWS secret manager from outside its environment, I mean locally in this case, but production won't be part of AWS environment either. I am using the code snippet that amazon is providing for C#.
using Amazon;
using Amazon.SecretsManager.Model;
using Amazon.SecretsManager;

namespace Project.ApplicationService;

public class AwsCredentialsProcessor
{
    public async Task<AwsCredentials> GetAwsCredentials()
    {
        string secretName = "****";
        string region = "****";

        IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

        GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest
        {
            SecretId = secretName
        };

        GetSecretValueResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        string secret = response.SecretString;

        return new AwsCredentials(null, null);
    }
}

When I am trying to debug the api call I get the following error:
"Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service"
I have setup the secret in the secret manager.
I have created a user in IAM and assigned a group to it. The group has a policy to be able to retrieve data from secrets manager.
Is it possible to get the secret outside the aws environment programmatically?

I am not clear on what you mean by "outside of its  environment". You create a Servive Client in your C# app and you must specify your credentials. This is what is happening in your case. Yu need to specify the key and secrey key values.
using Amazon;
using Amazon.SecretsManager.Model;
using Amazon.SecretsManager;

namespace Project.ApplicationService;

public class AwsCredentialsProcessor
{
    public async Task<AwsCredentials> GetAwsCredentials()
    {
        string secretName = "****";
        string region = "****";
        string accessKey = "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID";
        string secretKey = "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY";

        IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(
            accessKey,
            secretKey,
            RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

        GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest
        {
            SecretId = secretName
        };

        GetSecretValueResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        string secret = response.SecretString;

        return new AwsCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }
}

